# Unable to access Google Console from another laptop

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a new google account and had set up a VM instance under the Google Console. I am able to access all features of that console on the computer where it was initially set up, but unable to access the VM instance on any other computer. I am able to log into that google account successfully on any computer and when i access  google console i get the following error:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page
You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:
Project
resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
```

Going back to the original laptop where i do have access, there is nothing obvious under IAM that needs to be added. Please advise if anyone has had any experience with this.

Comment: Edit your question and include the commands that you are using. Most likely you are authenticating with different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are by default of the new machine logging in using a different G account. That or the incorrect project is selected. Theres a dropdown in the top middle just off to the right. The IAM throws me off a little bit so Im not certain.